# isPalindrome - how comparison is being executed in `else if (str.length===2) return str[0]===str[1] `?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, palindrome

I understand the 3rd Conditional but not 2nd one

On the 2nd Conditional - if the length of "str" is 2 (meaning it has 2 characters) then return "str[0] === str[1]" but what if those last two characters are different "c" "g" maybe?

how comparison is being executed in `return str[0] === str[1]` ? does the comparison have to be inside if() statement because if() statement returns true ?

However, this line `return str[0] === str[1]` being outside the scope of if() statement  return true or false

```html
function isPalindrome(str) {
  // 1st Conditional
  if (str.length === 1) return true 

  // 2nd Conditional
  else if (str.length===2) return str[0]===str[1] 
  
  // 3rd Conditional
  else if (str[0] === str.slice(-1)) {
    return isPalindrome(str.slice(1,-1))
  }

  return false
}
```

Comment: `return str[0]===str[1]` if the values match, you get `return true`, otherwise `return false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `return "str[0] === str[1]"`, but what if those last two characters are different "c" "g" maybe?

This statement will return a boolean value. That boolean value is determined by `str[0] === str[1]`. This is a comparison that is either false or true. In the example "cg", that comparison will evaluate to false, and so the `return` statement will make the function return with the value `false`.

> how comparison is being executed in `return str[0] === str[1]`?

It is executed like in any other context. The expression is `str[0] === str[1]`, and the result of that evaluation is returned by the `return` statement.

> does the comparison have to be inside `if()` statement because `if()` statement returns true ?

The `return` should only be executed when the preceding `if` statement is true, i.e. that `return` should only be executed when the length of the string is true.

> However, this line `return str[0] === str[1]` being outside the scope of `if()` statement return true or false

That statement is **not** outside the scope of the `if` statement. It is a statement that is only executed when the `if` condition is true.

If it helps, we could rewrite that `if (str.length===2) return str[0]===str[1]` as follows:

```
if (str.length===2) {
    let isPalindromeOfTwo = str[0]===str[1];
    return isPalindromeOfTwo;
}
```

Or even (but this is an antipattern):

```
if (str.length===2) {
    if (str[0]===str[1]) {
        return true; // It is a palindrome of 2
    } else {
        return false; // Not a palindrome
    }
}
```

Just realise that a comparison represents a **value**: a boolean value. This value can be used in any context that requires a value. You can for instance do any of these:

```
console.log(str[0]===str[1]); // output will be "false" or "true"
let x = str[0]===str[1]; // x will be a boolean value: false or true
let y = Number(str[0]===str[1]); // y will be a number, 0 or 1
```

Comment: Thank  you for you time and concise answer. The issue with me was I never though that " === " returns boolean true or false. I thought statement has to be inside if statement if(here===here). I got the answer. thank you so much